# Python program to plot the distance the ball is thrown

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to teach myself python. I have been going through this book, and a problem has been stumping me. I just began to learn plotting with pylab. The question is to plot the distance the ball is thrown from t = 0. Some of the numbers given were v = 5, t = 0, y = 3.

This is the formula that I think I should be using R = (v^2*sin(2θ))/g. Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
 import pylab
 import math

 pylab.figure(1)
 pylab.plot(((5**2)*(math.sin(2))/3)
 pylab.show()
```

It just prints out a blank graph. I know that I am probably doing the formula wrong, in conjunction with not using pylab properly. Just kind of confused on where to go next with this.

Comment: You just calculate one number. What kind of plot do you expect to get from this?

Comment: Where do you want to go?

Answer (score 0):

you plot *y* over *x* therefore you have to define *x*

the following is from the pyplot tutorial http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles  you can change this see the tutorial
plt.plot(t, INSERT YOUR FUNCTION HERE, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

the correct function for a trajectory of a projectile is y(x)= x*tan(beta)-({g}/{2*[v^2]*[cos^2(beta)]})*[x^2]

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile